# No longer see create date in opject details for views

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am using SQL Server 2005 (v9.00.5000). I was using SSMS v9.00.1399 when my machine failed. A new machine was built by my company but it came with SMSS 10.0.16.

Now I when I go to the Object Explorer detail for views, I no longer see the columns that were there (namely the `createdate` is what I need need) but instead I see only the view name and an empty column with the header "Policy Health State" I admit that I am pretty "old school", but I don't know what this is telling me and contacting my IT Net Admin guy gets me a shrug.

What do I need to do to get the columns I had before back instead of this Policy Health State?

I also noticed that I get a perpetual "spinning donut" cursor when ever I try to look at the Object Explorer Detail screen.

Can someone tell me what this all means (or at least what to look at?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right click and select columns?

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on header of Object Explorer Detail tab and select Create Date.
[image]

Here is two sql query also you can use.

```
select * from sys.tables
select * from sys.views
```

Comment: I have added another ss showing what I see if I right click on the header. as you can see, I only have the two columns displayed as options.  No create date.